# Compact Matrix representation for duplicate eigen values

Tags: transient, matrix

For a diagonal matrix with diagonal elements equal to eigen values, I am interested to further use this matrix to carry out transient analysis using a numerical method (trapezoidal rule).
There are large number (thousands) of very similar (almost same) eigen values in this matrix but I can't take them all due to computational complexity and very long run time required for transient analysis for such a high dimensional matrix.
Taking only a few most significant eigen values (corresponding to the most dominant poles) make the results very inaccurate and hence doesn't serve the purpose.

Need some guidance if there's a way to deal with this accuracy vs long run time issue?
In short if there's some way to compactly represent the matrix having thousands of duplicate eigen values & use the compact Matrix for transient analysis.

Comment: Hi! I'm not sure what your matrix represents? Could you elaborate? I'm not aware of how such a matrix relates to transient analysis, so a bit of just stating what's in the matrix (I guess some observations?) and what you do to get the transients from that would help – I don't think most people here know what you're talking about